# Namcheap gem won't work for my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

New to rails, and this is my first API. I'm trying to incorporate the Namecheap API into my Rails app so users can choose and register domains without leaving my site. I did '$ gem install namecheap', then put the following in config/initializers/application.rb:

```
require 'namecheap'  
Namecheap.configure do |config|  
  config.key = 'mykey'  
  config.username = 'myusername'  
  config.client_ip = 'myip'  
end  
Namecheap.domains.get_list
```

When I try to start up the server, I get the error:

```
/Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/namecheap-0.2.0/lib/monkey_patch.rb:61:in `module_eval': (__DELEGATION__):2: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
class.__send__(:railtie_name, *args, &block)
```

Any advice? My ruby version is 2.0.0p451, and rails version is 4.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

you may edit in your gemfile as `gem 'namecheap'` and run the server. And refer [this link](http://rubydoc.info/gems/namecheap/0.2.0/frames) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was actually the guide I used to set it up. I already have the namecheap gem in my Gemfile. Any other ideas?